# Adding quantity if the product is exist in the DataGridView

Tags: vb.net

Can someone help me with my problem?

The picture below shows the same item I inputted. What I want is I don't like to show duplicate items in DataGridView. If the same product record adds, then the new will not be showed, it just add the quantity when clicking the "Save" button. And I don't know how to code it I'm just new to vb.net. Can somebody help me how to do it?? It would be a big help for me if you do, thank you so much!

[image: pic1]

Below is my code for Save button:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        initializeCon()

    Dim found As Boolean = False

    If (DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0) Then
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            If (Convert.ToString(row.Cells(1).Value) = dtDate.Text) And (Convert.ToString(row.Cells(2).Value) = txtProductCode.Text) AndAlso
            (Convert.ToString(row.Cells(3).Value) = txtProductName.Text) Then
                row.Cells(4).Value = Convert.ToString(txtQuantity.Text + Convert.ToInt16(row.Cells(4).Value))
                found = True
            End If
        Next
        If Not found Then
            cmd = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_productOrders VALUES('" & txtID.Text & "','" & dtDate.Text & "','" & txtProductCode.Text & "','" & txtProductName.Text & "'," & txtQuantity.Text & ");", con)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            clrtxt()
            SaveMsg()
            Getdata()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code

Comment: I already post it @patel, sorry hehehe

Comment: code for Add Button missing

Comment: add button is for just enabling the textboxes

Comment: how do you populate the dgv ? how do you add rows ?

Comment: by clicking "Save" button

Comment: it saves the data to sql server with table name (tbl_productOrders) and then populate to the dgv

Answer (score 0):

this is an axample to avoid duplicates while adding rows

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim exist As Boolean = False, numrow As Integer = 0, numtext As Integer 
    For Each itm As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        If itm.Cells(0).Value IsNot Nothing Then
            If itm.Cells(0).Value.ToString = TextBox1.Text Then
                exist = True
                numrow = itm.Index
                numtext = CInt(itm.Cells(1).Value)
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
    If exist = False Then
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New String() {TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text})
    Else
        DataGridView1.Rows(numrow).Cells(1).Value = CInt(TextBox2.Text) + numtext
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two aspects to improve your program.

**1. Make comparing products better**

Since you need to check individual properties to find equal product, the better way is to overload `==` operator along with implementing [IEquatable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1) interface. You can read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/how-to-define-value-equality-for-a-type). When you do this, you can compare products with `==` operator: `if (product1 == product2) { }`. In this case three properties are being compared. If they all are the same, then two products are equal.

**2. Make adding products to DataGridView easier**

In order to make adding products to DataGridView easier, you need to leverage the handy binding mechanism in Windows Forms, which appeared in .NET Framework 2.0 - [BindingSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource). It acts like a medium between your data and controls. In order to make this class usable, you need to use another handy class - [BindingList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.bindinglist-1). You feed BindingList to BindingSource and assign BindingSource to DataSource property of DataGridView. After that you work only with BindingList collection (adding/removing/editing) - and all the propagation is done by BindinSource.

**To summarize**, here is the explanation and full code. [Here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvqfUD6Rp0UCk2RBpGkew0VDjwEy) you can download the project itself.

1. When you add product, the code first checks whether such product already exists in DataGridView (`Add product` button). Do note that we don't work with DataGridView directly - we work *only* with the collection. Thanks to enhancements, we can use LINQ here. If the product is not found, we add it to collection. If it's found, we just update the quantity.
2. If you need to update selected product data (`Change quantity` button), you only need to retrieve it from selected rows and use `BoundDataItem` - this is where our product is located. Then just update properties of product you need.
3. If you need to remove product (`Delete product` button), retrieve it from selected row and delete it from the collection.

*Important!* Do not forget to call `Refresh()` method on DataGridView after all taken actions in order to see the changes.

[image: IMG1]

```
namespace WinFormsApp
{
    public partial class Root : Form
    {

        private BindingList<Product> list = null;
        private BindingSource bindingSource = null;

        public Root() => InitializeComponent();

        private void OnFormLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Our collection holding products
            list = new BindingList<Product>();
            // I've set up columns manually (with applied binding),
            // so switch generating columns off.
            dataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            // Disable adding new row
            dataGrid.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            // Create our medium between grid and collection
            bindingSource = new BindingSource { DataSource = list };
            // Set binding
            dataGrid.DataSource = bindingSource;
        }

        private void OnAddRecord(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Create new product
            var new_product = new Product
            {
                Date = dtPicker.Value.ToShortDateString(),
                Code = txtCode.Text,
                Name = txtName.Text,
                Quantity = npQuantity.Value
            };
            // No need to check individual properties here
            // as == and IEquatable will do all the work.
            // We can safely use LINQ here.
            var p = list.FirstOrDefault(x => x == new_product);
            if (p == null)
            {
                // Product is not found. Add it to list.
                list.Add(new_product);
            }
            else
            {
                // Product is found. Update quantity.
                p.Quantity += new_product.Quantity;
            }
            dataGrid.Refresh(); //Required to reflect changes
        }

        private void OnChangeQuantity(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Change quantity here.
            var product = GetProduct();
            if (product != null)
            {
                // Update product's quantity.
                product.Quantity *= 2;
                // Do not forget to refresh grid.
                dataGrid.Refresh();
            }
        }

        private void OnDeleteProduct(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Delete product here.
            var product = GetProduct();
            if (product != null)
            {
                // We need to delete product only from collection
                list.Remove(product);
                // Do not forget to refresh grid
                dataGrid.Refresh();
            }
        }

        // Retrieve product from selected row.
        private Product GetProduct() =>
            dataGrid.SelectedCells.Count == 0 ?
                null :
                dataGrid.SelectedCells[0].OwningRow.DataBoundItem as Product;
    }

    class Product : IEquatable<Product>
    {
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Quantity { get; set; }

        // Overload == operator
        public static bool operator ==(Product firstProduct, Product secondProduct)
        {
            // Check for null on left side.
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(firstProduct, null))
            {
                if (Object.ReferenceEquals(secondProduct, null))
                {
                    // null == null = true.
                    return true;
                }
                // Only the left side is null.
                return false;
            }
            // Equals handles case of null on right side.
            return firstProduct.Equals(secondProduct);
        }

        // Overload != operator (required when overloading == operator)
        public static bool operator !=(Product firstProduct, Product secondProduct) =>
              !(firstProduct == secondProduct);

        // Implementing IEquatable<T> interface
        public bool Equals(Product other)
        {
            // If 'other' is null, return false.
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(other, null))
            {
                return false;
            }

            // Optimization for a common success case.
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, other))
            {
                return true;
            }

            // If run-time types are not exactly the same, return false.
            if (this.GetType() != other.GetType())
            {
                return false;
            }

            // Return true if the fields match.
            return
                Date == other.Date &&
                Code == other.Code &&
                Name == other.Name;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj) => this.Equals(obj as Product);

        public override int GetHashCode() =>
            Date.GetHashCode() + Code.GetHashCode() + Name.GetHashCode();

        // Optional. For debugging purposes.
        public override string ToString() =>
            $"Date: {Date}, Code: {Code}, Name: {Name}, Quantity: {Quantity}";
    }
}
```